# Can I export an object using `export` as "`module.export`"

Tags: ecmascript-6, amd

I think what I am asking for is not possible OOB, but I want to confirm.

We are in a process of upgrading to ES6 (using Babel). Project is a web-site, using AMD (requirejs). I would like to turn a utility module (`foolib`) into ES6, but consume it from *either* ES6 (using `import`) or existing ES5/AMD module.

```
// foolib.es6
export { // as expected, this doesn't work
    method1: function () { ... },
    value1: 123.456
};

// consumer1.es6
import foolib from "foolib";

// consumer2.js
define(["foolib"], function (foolib) {});
```

I understand that the solution is to change `foolib.es6` as follows:

```
export function method1() { ... };
export let value1 = 123.456;
```

However in reality number of entries returned from `foolib` is ridiculous. So I was hoping there is a way to export existing object literal without rewriting every line.

Furthermore, I realize that this is most likely impossible, due to the differences between AMD import (using `define`) and `import` mechanism (later works with `exports` object that has values hanging off of it, including `default` value, while former expects a single value to be returned).

One possible solution that I think might work is to export my object as `default` from `foolib.es6`, and then tweak requirejs default loader to inspect imported value for being an esModule and return default value: `value && value.__esModule && value.default || value`. Should this work? (I'm still hoping there is an easier solution).

Comment: `export default { method1: function () {}, ... }` and [`babel-plugin-add-module-exports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports)

Comment: @sdgluck: yep, that did it. Works with both consumers. Make it an answer please. Please include a gotcha that this plugin _must_ be included _before_ any -modules- plugin (`transform-es2015-modules-amd` in my case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you are using to export the object is invalid because you are not giving the object a name, so it cannot be a named export, and you are not specifying that it is the default export, so it cannot be the default export. Change it to be the default export:

```
// foolib.es6
export default {
  method1: function () {}, 
  value1: 123.456
}
```

```
// consumer.es6
import foolib from "foolib";

console.log(foolib.value) //=> 123.456
```

---

You can use the [`babel-plugin-add-module-exports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) Babel plugin to reinstate a default export as the value of `module.exports` in Node-land.

And as you discovered, make sure you include this plugin before any other `-modules-` plugins, for example `transform-es2015-modules-amd`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but alternatively you can use the [named `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports) as well which is a little different from the `default` approach that @sdgluck mentioned.

```
const method1 = function () {};
const value1 = 123.456;

export { method1, value1 };
```

I like this approach because you can `import` them directly like

```
import { method1, value1 } from 'foolib';
```

without reaching out to the `default` variable.